# How to make graph in GNU plot with the given data without interpolation and showing missing data?

Tags: python, graph, dataset, gnuplot

I have a .csv file as shown in the [data_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ngza.png).
First column is the density, second is altitude, third is latitude and last one is longitude. I want to make a graph like this  visualise.

[image]

But i am getting something like this.
[image]

So my graph looks like a global coverage but i have missing data. Also, when first column is negative i want to ignore that row and plot other row. My gnuplot script is like this;

```
set cntrparam levels auto
set dgrid3d 150,100,4
set pm3d corners2color c1
set contour
unset surface
unset key
set pm3d map
set view map
set lmargin 5
set rmargin 6                                                               
set tmargin 2                                                            
set bmargin 2
splot 'new.csv' using 3:2:1 with pm3d notitle
```

How i can make a graph like I showed? And how I can ignore the rows where the first column is negative or how can make a row NaN where the first column is negative? Thank you so much in advance.

Best.

I tried set pm3d corners2color c1 to remove interpolation but that did not work as well. Also, How can make that graph in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [contour plot with gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76996462/contour-plot-with-gnuplot)

Comment: Please clarify or expand your original question rather than starting a new one. Also please do not present data or script commands as a png image.  Enter the text as part of the question.

Comment: Hello Ethan, This question is new and different from previous one. I can write the script here as you want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want interpolation, then I think you probably don't want a surface plot (`splot with pm3d`) at all.   Perhaps this 2D plot is closer to what you want.  I don't have your data, but here is a longitude/latitude plot with scattered data. Your data is more regularly spaced, so you can avoid overlapping points by choosing a suitable point size.

```
set xlabel "Longitude"
set ylabel "Latitude"
unset key
set pointsize 2.0   # adjust size to taste, or to make the squares touch
set palette cubehelix
plot 'cor.dat' using 3:2:1 with points pt 5 lc palette
```

[image]

NaN values will not produce a point.

Filtering out negative points is usually done with a test like this:
`plot FOO using (column(1)<0 ? NaN : column(3)):2:1`

Comment: Hello Ethan, Thank you so much for your response. I think I solved the issue finally. I used heat map as an example.

Comment: Great.  Please either accept the answer that led to a solution, or add your own solution as an "answer" and accept that one.  We want future searches to be able to distinguish solved problems from unsolved problems.